# Github redirect from sign-out to sign-in page instead of homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, greasemonkey, userscripts

I would to redirect to sign-in page when sign-out instead of redirect to homepage in github.

Any idea how I can do with an userscript? I would be grateful for assistance.

Here is how the form snippet look:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="header-nav-item">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/logout" class="logout-form" method="post">
      <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" />
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="123465789" />
      </div>
      <button class="header-nav-link sign-out-button tooltipped tooltipped-s" aria-label="Sign out" data-ga-click="Header, sign out, icon:logout"> <span class="octicon octicon-sign-out">Sign out</span>

      </button>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In your post request add res.redirect("http://github.com");

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, but where I can add this. Will this work with tampermonkey and greasemonkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some solution for Tampermonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @author       You
// @match        https://github.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var myRedirectStorageKey = 'redirectMeToLogin';

if ( localStorage.getItem( myRedirectStorageKey ) ) {
    localStorage.removeItem( myRedirectStorageKey );
    window.location.href = 'https://github.com/login';
}

$( '.sign-out-button' ).on( 'click', function() {
   localStorage.setItem( myRedirectStorageKey, true );
} );
```